# What are the differences between photographic, fine art, velvet, cotton textured, and German Etching paper?

Tags: printing, paper

The shop that prints out photographs in my city offers these different options.

I don't really know what option to choose. I just want to print out some colour or monochrome photo's as boxed canvases and put them up in our living room.

Anything I should be aware of? Why do people prefer certain types more?
Hahnemühle German Etching paper is the most expensive it seems. Does it favour a photo with more texture?

I hope this isn't too general.

Comment: Do you want paper prints or canvas prints?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that you ask for some samples to the provider. You probably could ask a small sized reproduction of one of your photos on different papers, and see the results.

You can still use this samples in your house, and then, after the experience, sending the file for a big print.